# Laravel Blade create Button with child

Tags: php, laravel, append, laravel-blade

I want to convert the HTML Button to a Laravel Form button. I dont know how.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Benutzer hinzufügen
</button>
```

In my blade template it looks now like this:

```
{!! Form::submit('Benutzer hinzufügen', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-primary')) !!}
```

Is there an option like this?

```
{!! Form::submit('Benutzer hinzufügen', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-primary', 'child' => '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>')) !!}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Benutzer hinzufügen', array('class' => 'btn btn-block btn-primary', 'type' => 'submit')) !!}
```

It will work for what you want!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help! :)